# What is the best way to save byte array in flutter's shared preferences?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, byte

I have a bunch of byte arrays that I have to save in my flutter application.

At the moment I convert those byte arrays to base64, and saving them as a single line string.

Is there any better way to save bytes using shared preferences lib/some other lib?

Comment: You could create a local database (SqlLite?). And store the bytes directly in a BLOB column of a table. I'm not going to say it's the "better" way because that's debatable and subjective. The benefit would be that you shouldn't have to do as many data transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base64 encode is good start, but it will produce very long string.
How about adding additional process by compress those bytes first using gzip, and then save it on local storage using `SharedPreference` or `Hive`

```
import 'dart:convert';

...

final gZipBytes = gzip.encode(bytesArray);
localStorage.save(key, base64.encode(gZipBytes));
```